# program doesn't stop and continues to run

Tags: c++, vector

This program is supposed to return nth prime using two functions, `nthPrime(n)` and `isPrime(candidatePrime, Vector<int >&primes)`. We store the checked numbers that are prime in a vector and then divide the successive candidate by elements from the vector. But my program doesn't stop and no output is shown.

The code is :

[image: isPrime(int candidatePrime,Vector<int >&primes]

Comment: Post your [mcve] as text in the question, not as an image.

Comment: One problem is that you add a candidate to the container before checking it against *all* other values in the container. That way the `size()` will grow almost every time, and `i` might never reach it.

Comment: how do I make the candidate to check against all prime numbers ? if division is possible by any of the number, then the candidate is not prime and then the decider goes false. then what do I have to do ? 
do I add some && condition such as if candidate is not divisible by any numbers,  then set decider as true ?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to remove the line where you add to the container (line 94) outside the for loop.

Comment: ok , I will but then where do I store my already sorted primes ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes of the problem you're facing as @bo persson has also mentioned
is that you add a candidate to the container before checking it against all the other values in the container. Hence the size() will grow almost every time, and "i" might never reach it.

@farhat has provided one solution to the issue however, an alternative to farhat's answer could be using another vector to add the items there and keep the statement where it currently is.